# Двойные кавычки в адресной строке

Tags: apache, php, denwer

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь сделать ЧПУ на сайте. Тестирую на Denwer. Вот содержимое файла `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://site.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://site.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ (.*)//+(.*)\  [NC]
RewriteRule .* %1/%2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?
RewriteRule .*  404/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://site.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /?url=$1 [L]
```

В принципе, сделал все как планировал, однако есть непонятный для меня момент. Если я пытаюсь перейти по адресу [site.com/testpage/,](http://site.com/testpage/,) то все происходит как я планировал - выполняется скрипт в `index.php`, в качестве `GET` параметра `url` передается testpage/. Однако, если я добавлю двойные кавычки ([site.com/test"page/),](http://site.com/test) то происходит совсем не то, что я ожидаю - вместо того, чтобы просто поменять значение `GET` параметра `url`, появляется страница с сообщением об ошибке:

> You don't have permission to access
> /test"page/ on this server.

В связи с этим, хотелось бы понять, почему так происходит. Правильно ли я понимаю, что здесь дело в неправильных настройках апача? Пытался гуглить по этому поводу, но, к сожалению, ничего не нашел.

Comment: у тебя страницы так и будут называться test"page ? если нет, то просто забудь!

Comment: Нужен ответ по существу.

Comment: а чем не по существу? и чего вы"ожидаете от работы скрипта?

Comment: Я хочу разобраться в вопросе, а не оставлять все на авось. Да, я не планирую использовать двойные кавычки, но не хочу, чтобы человек, который введет их в адресной строке, увидел именно такую страницу с ошибкой. Что я ожидаю от работы скрипта я уже писал - GET параметр url должен иметь значение test"page/ (потом смотрится, есть ли такая страница в базе, если нет - 404 редирект).

Comment: читать [тут][1] и запомнить! Если в адресной строке кавычки, нужно и необходимо отправлять на 404 и делать все что заблокирует работу скрипта!


  [1]: http://www.phpfaq.ru/slashes

Comment: @Palmervan, волков бояться - в лесу не ... Неправильно чего-то не делать, если это опасно - надо принять меры предосторожности, а не отказываться и прятаться под кровать :)

Answer (score 1):

Я, честно, не стал копаться, где у вас ошибка, но кавычки проблемой не являются. Мое:

`.htaccess:`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /url.php?u=$1
```

`url.php:`

```
<pre><? var_dump($_GET); ?></pre>
```

`GET /asdf"asd:!@2$/`

```
array(1) {
  ["u"]=>
  string(14) "asdf"asd:!@2$/"
}
```

Comment: Возможно дело в том как именно вы посылаете запрос. Если вы посылаете запрос через браузер, браузер автоматически заменяет двойные кавычки на `%22`. Если же через телнет, то тогда странно. На моём опыте Apache 2.4 тоже отвечает 403 на любой запрос, содержащий двойную кавычку в URI. Сорри за некропостинг.